# Here javascript vendor migration

Tags: here-api

To be able to use apikey to authenticate. I migrated NokieHere javascript libraries from 3.0 to 3.1. But unluckily my existing code breaks because of a lot of changes from in here core javascript code.

I need to configure the plateform as following :

```
const platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: 'my-api-key'
});

let customeRouter = {...} // this object aims to pass the waypoints in the request body to avoid having a very long URL ...

platform .configure(customeRouter);
```

In 3.1 javascript version, the `configure()` method was removed. So anyone guys did the NokiaHere javascripts libraries migration ?

Thank you in advance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Platform#configure()` method has been removed.

Here is the user guide for migrating from version 3.0 to version 3.1: [HERE javascript API migration guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html)

Comment: I finally migrated from 3.0 to 3.1 but I have an issue while rendering the map. the following error pops when I instanciate a new Map : Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob when doing Here quick start guide. (PS : I am using emberjs as a framework)

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle link? There is posibility to add emberjs framework.